# Do all holomorphic functions on $\{z^2 + w^2 = 1\}$ extend to $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let
$$X = \{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : z^2 + w^2 = 1\}.$$
Is there a holomorphic function $f : X \to \mathbb{C}$ which do not extend to a holomorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

---

I tried to find an example of the form $f(z, w) = \frac{1}{g(z, w)}$, where $g(z, w)$ is a holomorphic function which has zeros, but none that lie in $X$. But I couldn't find any.

Comment: Do you want $f$ to be  a function $X \to \mathbb C^2$ or $X \to \mathbb C$? I don't think it really matters though...

Comment: @red_trumpet $X \to \mathbb{C}$; thanks for catching this typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Claim.* Every holomorphic function on $X = \{\, (z,w) : z^2 + w^2 = 1 \,\} \subset \mathbb C^2$ extends to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C^2$.

*Proof.*
Introducing the new coordinates
$$s = z + iw, \quad t = z - iw$$
we see that
$$X = \{\, s \cdot t = 1 \,\}.$$
The projection $\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C, (s,t) \mapsto s$ induces an isomorphism
$$X \stackrel{\cong}{\rightarrow} \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$$
By this isomorphism we can identify holomorphic functions on $X$ with holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ in one coordinate $s$. We can already construct functions on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ that do not extend to $\mathbb C$ but still extend from $X$ to $\mathbb C^2$! For example
$$f(s) = \frac{1}{s} = t. \tag{1}$$
Now we use this idea to prove our claim.

Let $f(s)$ be any holomorphic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Since $f$ has (at most) an isolated singularity in $0$, we can write $f$ as a Laurent series
$$f(s) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k s^k.$$
Since the only singularities of $f$ are in $0$ and in $\infty$, the two power series
$$g(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{-k} t^k, \quad h(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k s^k$$
have infinite radius of convergence, so that
$$f(s,t) = g(t) + h(s)$$
is an extension of $f$ to $\mathbb C^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one reason that you could not find a counterexample. Say you have $\psi(z,w)$ a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ that has no zeroes on $\{\phi=0\}$, that is $\phi$ and $\psi$ have no common zeroes.  Then take $\frac{1}{\psi(z,w)}$ and somehow get a contradiction. Now it turns out that if two $\phi$, $\psi$ have no common zeroes then there exist other two functions $a$, $b$ such that
$$a \phi + b \psi = 1$$

Therefore, on $\{\phi=0\}$ we have $\frac{1}{\psi} = b$, which extends. Uff...

Now, a general approach to the extension of functions from $\{\phi=0\}$ to the whole space.

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $X=\{\phi=0\}$. There exists an open cover $(U_n)_n$ of the whole space $\mathbb{C}^2$ and a family of holomorphic maps $F_n$ on $U_n$ such that
$$F_n\ _{\mid X\cap U_n} = f_{\mid X\cap U_n}$$
that is, $F_n$ locally extends $f$ from $X\cap U_n$ to $U_n$. Now, the problem is that $F_n$ do not piece together to form a function on $\mathbb{C}^2$. In other words,

$$F_m\ _{U_m \cap U_n} \not= F_n\ _{U_m \cap U_n}$$
just yet. However,
$$F_m\ _{U_m \cap U_n\cap X} = F_n\ _{U_m \cap U_n\cap X}$$

Now, if for a holomorphic function $G$ on $U$ open subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ we have
$$G_{\mid U \cap \{\phi=0\}} = 0$$
then
$$G = \phi\cdot H$$
for some holomorphic function on $U$ ( the converse is obvious). This is not difficult to prove, but requires an argument. Let's leave it for now.

In any case, we have

$$(F_m - F_n)_{\mid U_m \cap U_n} = \phi\cdot G_{m n}$$
for some function $G_{mn} \colon U_{mn} \to \mathbb{C}$, holomorphic.

Now, we would like to write
$$G_{mn} = H_m- H_n$$
for some functions $H_\colon U_m \to \mathbb{C}$. That would give us
$$F_m - F_n = \phi( H_m - H_n)$$
and so
$$F_m - \phi \cdot H_m = F_n - \phi \cdot H_n$$
on $U_m\cap U_n$
and so
$$\tilde F_n \colon = F_n - \phi \cdot H_n$$
piece together into a function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ that restricts to $f$.

How to get the $H_n$'s?  We have
$$G_{mn}+ G_{nk}+ G_{km}= 0$$ on $U_m\cap U_n\cap U_k$ so they form a cocycle (Cech cohomology). Now, every cocycle is in fact a coboundary ( this follows from some existence result for the $\bar \partial $ problem).

Recommended text: Hormander, Several Complex Variables

Note: this result holds in general: if $X$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $f\colon X\to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then there exists $F\colon \mathbb{C}^n$ that restricts to $f$. The proof is similar, but there are complications. It would be essentially the same if $X$ was the zero set of $\phi$, with $0$ a regular value.  In codimension larger than $1$  one deals with "sheaves of (ideals of) holomorphic functions", and some discipline is required.

Why is this more complicated than the smooth case? There we have the partition of $1$, something that does not exists in the holomorphic case.

Comment: Is $G|_{\{\phi=0\}} = 0 \implies G = \phi \cdot H$ an application of [Rückert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz#Analytic_Nullstellensatz_(R%C3%BCckert%E2%80%99s_Nullstellensatz))?

Comment: @red_trumpet:Indeed,  It may be so :-) The recommendation is "prove it by hand".

Comment: @red_trumpet: One can show by hand (very instructive) that $H^{1}(\mathfrak{U}, \mathcal{O}) = 0$ for the cover $\mathfrak{U} = (\mathbb{C},\tilde{\mathbb{C}}\backslash\{0\})$ of $\tilde {\mathbb{C}}$.  :-)