# Do all holomorphic functions on a smooth affine variety $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ extend to $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $X$ be a non-singular complex affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let
$$f : X \to \mathbb{C}$$
be a holomorphic function.
Does $f$ extend to a holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$?

This question is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4490594/39285) one, where the answer is shown to be yes in the special case where
$$ X = \{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : z^2 + w^2 = 1\}.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is yes.

First, the ideal sheaf $I_X$ of $X$ is a coherent analytic sheaf. So there is an exact sequence of coherent analytic sheaves

$$0\to I_X\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C^n}\to \mathcal{O}_X\to 0.$$

[Cartan's theorem B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorems_A_and_B) implies that $H^1(I_X)=0$. So there is surjectivity

$$H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb C^n})\twoheadrightarrow H^0(\mathcal{O}_X).$$